# CreateJS toolkit and Flash

Tags: flash, createjs

Since the Toolkit for CreateJS extension is so new, there are many features within Flash that are not yet supported. For example, version 1.1 supports motion tweens, but version 1.0 did not. The solution was to use classic tweens rather than motion tweens. Toolkit for CreateJS, version 1.1 also publishes shape tweens and masks to HTML5. It still does not publish embedded fonts. What would be a workaround to this unsupported feature? What are the other unsupported features? What are workarounds for these unsupported features?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a direct answer here. It's a wide question that can get pretty scattered because there are so many topis under the "What Flash can do, how do you do it with CreateJS using Flash as an authoring tool?" umbrella.

Regaring the "newness" of things, it's been around for a number of years by now. I think Grant Skinner may have began initial work on these libraries back in 2012, or even 1-2 years beforehand. I'd guess it wasn't until CS5 or CS6 that he/his team & Adobe got to the point of the Toolkit concept and having them help Flash authors use the libraries in a not-so-manual kind of way.

By now, Toolkit is no longer supported. I think it was an interim concept when Flash CS 6 was around; it did what was needed those couple years ago, and it WAS needed because the Flash program wasn't engineered to a point where it integrated CreateJS libraries. But now, with Flash CC, the Toolkit isn't needed any more as it's become integrated into the creation/publishing of Flash "HTML5 Canvas" files. By publishing as the HTML5 canvas, you're essentially using what Toolkit did before.

As far as support of things from Flash to HTML5 Canvas, I'm sure there will always be a substantial gap there. It's a tough thing for many Flash developers to find out how to create what they created in the past going forward without the SWF runtime. A big piece of this is just knowing what is possible with CSS & JavaScript and what old + modern browsers support, but another piece is finding out if your tool (Flash CC, Edge Animate, or something else) can provide you with an advanced authoring environment + robust browser capabilities.

FWIW, here's an old Adobe forum posting asking a similar question with some good responses:
https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1243214

For some unsupported features, here is an incomplete list of warnings generated while copying/importing in your FLA file:

- AntiAlias is not supported in HTML5 Canvas document, and has been converted to DeviceFonts in an instance of Text.
- AutoKern is not supported in HTML5 Canvas document, and has been removed in an instance of Text.
- Frame Scripts have been commented
- LineType is not supported in HTML5 Canvas document, and has been converted to MultiLineNoWrap in an instance of Text.
- Some artwork contains Dashed stroke, which is not supported in HTML5 Canvas document, and has been converted to Solid.
- StaticText is not supported in HTML5 Canvas document, and has been converted to DynamicText in an instance of Text.

Here is an Adobe link of unsupported HTML5 Canvas features:
https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/unsupported-features-html5-canvas1.html